# Mathematica documentation in PDF

Tags: documentation

How can I find the pdf versions of the topics in Mathematica Documentation Center? It is not practical to open the pages of functions one by one and read. I am not talking about the tutorial collection.

Thanks

Comment: AFAICT, there aren't any PDFs of those. You could print the notebooks as PDFs, but that is a lot of work, and the rather haphazard system these days (as opposed to the tree system of older versions) make organization tedious. The docs were apparently optimized for searching, at the expense of easy browsing.

Comment: [This Wolfram site](https://www.wolfram.com/learningcenter/tutorialcollection/) has links to thousands of pages of documentation in freely downloadable PDFs.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries ...except that when you click on any of the "Download Free PDF" links, you get directed to the web version.  There's no PDF to download.

Comment: @QuantumDot hmmm, that used to work.

Comment: @QuantumDot archive.org still has them. For instance, try [this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150910032816/http://www.wolfram.com/learningcenter/tutorialcollection/CoreLanguage/CoreLanguage.pdf)